# Writing a ssh command which mysql dumps after a certain of rules are met

Tags: php, mysql, ssh

I'm writing a ssh/mysql script to mysqldump a secondary database back to a primary database after the primary has come back online.

Basically the way it works is;

The setup has 2 servers (Primary and secondary). Both run a parallel wordpress e-commerce website kept in sync using mysqldump and rsync every 5 minutes. I use a service called DNSmadeeasy Failover which checks for a viable connection. If the primary website is down, it switches to the secondary, then when the primary is back up, it changes the ip back to the primary server. If someone happens to register for the website or place an order, then the secondary now has the latest copy of the database.

The tutorial fails to go into detail on how to copy the latest version of the data inside the database back to the primary after it goes live. If the primary is down for a long time, the secondary server will then have the most up to date copy.

Is there a way of dumping the secondary database once a script has met a certain number of rules (for example)

1) check if primary database is up, if it is do nothing
else check if it's up again thenif its not up keep checking the status of the database until it is then run a mysqldump command to copy the data back to the primary

Comment: Do you really need multiple databases in the case or is it just the site you need to run multiple instances of? If you do then you probably want to use Mysql Replication not just a bunch dumps.

Comment: The primary server is on a vps and the secondary is on shared hosting, hence why I can't use master master replication (believe me that was my first thought) - I'm trying to work out a workaround)

Comment: Well then as always the proper answer is move the second server off the Shared hosting and into a small VPS :-) I just worry that the dumpfiles are actually going to cause you a larger problem over all unless you come up with some elaborate method to filter them based on some application specific criteria. I think you're going to need way more than just up/down checking.

Comment: If money was no object yes, but It's only a secondary server in case of emergency